# How to compare rows in order to fill missing values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe with 10 fields. Only in the 10th field there are missing data, and I need to fill them.

So let's say for a row, row-a, I have the 10th field empty. If there is a row-b such that for fields from 3 to 7 row-a and row-b have the same values, then I want to copy the value at 10th field of row-b to 10th field of row-a. And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you post raw input data for both dfs and what the expected output should be, at the moment it's hard to answer something so vague, but you could do `df[col].combine_first(df1[col])`

Comment: you can groupby field 3 to 7, and for every group fill NAN in field 10 with group mean.

Comment: Could you show a simple example to explain what you wanted to do?